# Как инициировать процесс снятия модератора в связи с необоснованным баном в чате?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, чат

Два моих сообщения, которые были удалены в чате, после которых последовал бан на 60 минут:

1. > я прошу Вас не указывать мне как общаться на русском языке, указывайте в других чатах, в чатах русского языка, к примеру. Тогда я не буду Вас трогать. [ссылка](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/46271487/history)
2. > не нужно прикрываться ромбом [ссылка](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/46271498/history)

Я никого не оскорблял, я не был невежлив. Человек просто решил меня забанить и забанил, заодно удалив мои сообщения. 
Очевидно, что этот человек злоупотребляет своей властью модератора для удовлетворения собственных прихотей.

В связи с чем, я хочу поднять вопрос о снятии с этой персоны привилегий модератора. Отсюда вопрос: как начать процесс и куда писать, чтобы в отношении неназванной в данном вопросе персоны были предприняты необходимые действия.

Comment: Ссылка во втором пункте битая?.. Скриншот бы не помешал.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, обе ссылки нормальные. Поверьте мне на слово, там то же самое содержание, просто там ещё и имя обсуждаемого модератора. А правилами запрещено тут такое выкладывать, поэтому не буду добавлять скриншот.

Comment: У меня там page not found. Может она только с 10k+ репы работает?

Comment: Не, там удалённые реплики из чата, их только автору и модерам видно

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> как начать процесс и куда писать, чтобы в отношении неназванной в данном вопросе персоны были предприняты необходимые действия.

1. Листаете текущую страницу до самого низа.
2. Нажимаете на ссылку ["Связаться с нами"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).
3. Выбираете в выпадающем списке "Я хочу обжаловать нарушение норм поведения" или "Другое".
4. Указываете всю дополнительную информацию по вашей проблеме, нажимаете кнопку "Отправить".

Comment: О, коротко и по делу.

Comment: А запрос уйдёт в модерку или лично к КМ?

Comment: @Suvitruf, точно не в модерку. куда-то выше

Answer (score -13):

Ваши сообщения были удалены, так как они нарушали правила:

> Никаких переходов на личности и персональных нападков.
>   Никакой травли.

Подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct.

Примечательно предложение «Тогда я не буду Вас трогать», которое свидетельствует о том, что имели место действия, направленные именно на личность.

Пожалуйста, будьте вежливы в общении с любыми участниками, независимо от их статуса.

Comment: Что значит «переход на личности и персональные выпады»? Мне баном не обезличенная машина угрожала, так же как указывала как мне использовать язык мне указывала не обезличенная машина. Поэтому правила тут никак не нарушены, я общался с источником, т.е. с личностью.

Comment: @ixSci нужно концентрироваться на действиях, а не на том, кто их сделал. Достаточно указать на их ошибочность, и модераторы или администрация найдут виновника и примут нужное решение.

Comment: Я вижу лишь бездействие. Единственным адекватным решением я вижу отставку модератора, который позволяет себе подобное.

Comment: @Aer: Вы не могли бы просто прекратить попытки модерировать наше сообщество? Мы вас не выбирали, и, видит бог, вы не вписываетесь в наше сообщество.

Comment: @VladD я не модерирую ваше сообщество, а модерирую чаты сети SE, когда на это есть время, и сайт о русском языке. Если имеет место нарушение правил, совершенно не важно, где оно произошло.

Comment: @Aer: Вы модерируете чат ru.SO, и успели снискать нелюбовь наверное всех, кроме администрации. Спасибо вам за вашу работу, но больше не нужно.

Comment: @Aer А вы бы ни могли, пожалуйста, уточнить какие именно были переходы на личности?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov например, «не нужно прекрываться ромбом», «Тогда я не буду Вас трогать». Участника несколько раз просили прекратить обсуждение личности другого участника, перейти к поступкам, к действиям, если это было нужно.

Comment: @Aer, где в приведённых цитатах _обсуждение_ личности. Это личное обращение к лицу, совершившему неправомерные выпады в мою сторону.

Comment: "прекрываться ромбом" - это **буква**льная цитата? Тогда правильно удалено ).