# Как решить проблему систематического флуда чата участником пустыми разговорами?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, чат, блокировка

### Предыстория

Когда-то на мете был случай блокировки участника с формулировкой ["за вредоносный шум"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3776/220571). Тот случай сильно отличается от данного тем, что тогда были [оскорбления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3786/220571) и всё-таки в том случае диалог был бессвязным и никем не поддерживался.

В данном случае всё посложней: я не видел никаких сообщений тянущих на бан. Бывали сообщения "на грани", с колкостями, бывали личные выпады, но явных оскорблений не было.

### О проблеме

Суть претензии: всё участие на сайте данного участника, сводится к демагогии в чате, продавливанию своих идей, доказыванию, голословным обвинениям и т.д. Длится это уже не первый месяц, что в целом полностью превратило повестку чата из программирования и каких-то отвлечённых тем в то, что здесь называется "драмой".

Я тоже бываю не согласен с действиями модераторов и сотрудников SE и тоже считаю, что и они не так и редко ошибаются. Но в этих сообщениях в чате редко бывает конструктив, это скорее похоже на смесь ложных обвинений, навешивания ярлыков и демагогии. Эти диалоги из которых состоит чат ни к чему не приводят, а лишь "переливают из пустого в порожнее", портят атмосферу чата и никак не учучшают наше сообщество.

### Что делать?

Я не могу какое-то отдельное сообщение выделить флагом. Также на мете встречал посты, описывающие кучу проблем с модерацией чатов, и особенно бывали проблемы с модерацией неанглоязычных чатов. Единственное решение, которое я вижу на данный момент — каким-то образом запросить бан. Но если можно каким-то образом пресечь оккупирование чата пустыми разговорами без блокировки, то это будет идеально. Проблема в том, что я не знаю каким образом нужно об этом сообщить, кроме как на мете. Уверен, что ситуация сама собой не "рассосётся".

Comment: Имхо, ответ такой же как [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7693/176217). Может быть даже стоит задубликатить. Хотя это всё же минует мод.состав, что не очень правильно.

Comment: Как смотрите на компромиссное решение -- выделить специально созданную комнатку, по примеру "политоты" (которую также не каждый хотел видеть в главной руме).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Я только за, пусть общается(-ются) в отдельных комнатах. Только вряд ли это устроит виновника(-ов) торжества, так как публики для их шоу будет маловато.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как инициировать процесс снятия модератора в связи с необоснованным баном в чате?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7689/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov механизм резолва тот же самый просто - обратиться через форму/чат. Но если вы считаете, что не дубликат, то могу отозвать голос)

Comment: @Suvitruf Вопросы крайне разные. А если для снятия модератора кто-то добавит другое решение или для борьбы с флудом ещё одно, то неужели его можно применить будет одинакого к обоим вопросам? А если ответ Влада применить к снятию модератора? Ответ "Я искренне надеюсь, что пути заблокировать **модератора**, который вам не нравится, нет, и никогда не будет." — к тому вопросу тоже сойдёт?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вы весьма убедительны)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @alexolut, ответ, вероятно, аналогичный: [Как инициировать процесс снятия модератора в связи с необоснованным баном в чате?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7689/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5/7693#7693)

Единственное, стоит учесть, что ваш запрос может обрабатываться какое–то время, пока попадет к правильному управляющему, а затем к модераторам, при необходимости. Как мне кажется, помимо запроса через обратную связь можно попросить модераторов создать закрытый чат и там объяснить проблему.

Также, чтобы ускорить процессы, можно связаться с управляющим, например, со мной, любым доступным и удобным способом (мои контакты указаны [в разделе о себе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile)). В личной переписке вы можете указать, что хотите обсудить/решить проблему с модераторами. Я создам закрытую комнату и приглашу туда модераторов.

Comment: А как просить создать закрытый чат? Где это делать? Жаль, кстати, что об этой опции я не слышал нигде в справке.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Какой–то особой опции нет. Просто упомянуть в любом удобном для вас месте о необходимости диалога с модераторами в закрытом чате.

Answer (score 9):

Я искренне надеюсь, что пути заблокировать участника, который вам не нравится, нет, и никогда не будет.

Если участник не нарушает правила, то его не за что блокировать. Правила о том, что участник обязательно должен на сайте давать ответы, обязательно вести дискуссию в чате так, чтобы вам понравилось, не пытаться убедить других в своих идеях, не критиковать никого — нет.

Поэтому проблема не в другом участнике, а только в вашем отношении к нему. Вам не нравится участник и вы не можете сделать так, чтобы он исчез? Смиритесь. Можете добавить его в игнор в чате.

Comment: Блин, а ведь идея. Сейчас есть баунти на вопросы, где ты жертвуешь репутацию. Можно сделать блокировку временную участника за репутацию. А ещё это можно монетизировать! Бан на месяц участника за 100$. Ух, дела у SE в гору пойдут :D

Comment: @Suvitruf бан высокорепового участника — $110

Comment: Защита от покупки бана — $200, действует неделю.

Comment: только массовые аукционы банов могут спасти ru.so!

Comment: Нужно всё-таки какое-то решение системаческого флуда в общем чате и его длительную оккупацию пустыми разговорами. Если это можно решить без блокировок, то я только за.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov коррекционное вмешательство)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: А в чём проблема? Ну создайте отдельный чат для флуда (он у нас уже был). Почему обязательно запретить, забанить, выгнать? Не вижу в вашем вопросе никакой толерантности.

Answer (score -1):

Решается очень просто с определённой долей вероятности, конечно же.

Необходимо определиться с тем, что считать разговорами "не по существу" и дополнить основные правила ruSO в связи с этим, при условии, что сообщество в целом за.

Comment: Точная формализация правил в соответствии с представлениями сообществва — это всегда хорошая идея. Проблема, однако же, в интерпретации. Мы, помнится, не смогли достичь консенсуса с модсоставом даже по поводу трактовки слова «агрессия», а уж что говорить о более тонких материях? (Минус не мой.)

Comment: @VladD [не смогли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7905/15479).

Comment: @Suvitruf: Потому что самоуправление модсостав отменил?