# Список тем, разрешённых для обсуждения в чате

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, чат, правила

Какие темы для чата допустимы?

1. Если учесть, что чат относится к контентной части сообщества, то может ли сообщество само составить список тем?
2. В FAQ чата указано, что можно обсуждать всё, что можно обсуждать на сайтах сети (в том числе и мете). Следовательно, любые вопросы про сообщество и проблемы допустимы в чате, если они явно не нарушают CoC и не растягиваются на дни, тем самым забивая основную комнату?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83371/discussion-on-question-by-suvitruf-------).

Comment: Голосовал за переоткрытие этого вопроса, так как вижу, что он не является дубликатом. Тот ответ концентрировался на каких-то абстрактных принципах модерирования и не даёт никакого чёткого ответа на поставленный в этой теме вопросы. Считаю, что нужно переоткрыть и дать ответы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Он другой: ваш про модерацию чата, а здесь просто хочется узнать список тем чата. В вашем ответе, также не совсем просто понять список тем, если хочется понять о чём можно общаться в чате.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вы в курсе, что я в чате забанен, вы сами бан выписали. Т.е, в вашей беседе в чате автор вопроса (в данном случае я)  в принципе не может ничего написать. Иронично.

Comment: Я не могу в чате писать, придётся здесь. Списка тем в FAQ нет. Написано, что разрешены темы, которые разрешены и на сайтах сети. Тогда администрация должна объяснить, почему запрещается обсуждать сообщество в чате. Администрация не раз повторял, что чат про программирование. Но мета является частью сети. Все вопросы, которые можно публиковать на мете, можно обсуждать и в чате.

Comment: @Suvitruf да, но если следовать такой логике - то и требования к обсуждениям на мете должны применяться к обсуждениям в чате.

Comment: @PashaPash ну да, требования CoC про "не оскорбляй", "без нападок", естественно остаются.

Comment: @Suvitruf не запрещается. Просто это не должно перерастать в лавину длиной в неделю. А через неделю приходят опоздавшие и еще неделю это перемалывают. Факты - ответы. Дискуссия затягивается - взяли в охапку оппонента и отошли в комнату, скажем "Проблемы сообщества".

Comment: @Nofate до прихода Николаса в чат было относительно спокойное обсуждение. Люди делились мнением, кто-то говорил, что тоже порой обидными видит en сообщения. Может, всё же, Николас не должен решать единолично за всех? Я сейчас именно про последний случай. В прошлые разы были перегибы со стороны некоторых пользователей, не спорю.

Comment: @PashaPash если "расширение онтопика у нас - через мету", то почему вопрос закрыт? Причём, наплевав на мнение тех, кто его переоткрыл, дважды?

Comment: @Suvitruf без паники, сейчас обсуждаем - дубликат или нет.

Comment: @PashaPash " (и тогда перевод FAQ, в развернутом виде) будет хорошим ответом" Хорошим, но не отвечающим полностью на вопрос. "второй вопрос (про обсуждение администрации)" Второй вопрос не про администрацию, а про то, что если обсуждение мета-вопросов в чате недопустимо, то что делать?

Comment: @Suvitruf я бы сказал, что оно допустимо, но должно следовать принципам меты, **не должно заменять мету**, и не уходить в бесконечные обсуждения и объяснению ситуации лично каждому, кто чуть опоздал. Например, я за 3 дня обсуждал один бан 4 раза, с разными участниками, и это дико выматывает.

Comment: @PashaPash чтоб поставить точку. Будет перевод FAQ, где сказано, что мета вопросы можно обсуждать в чате. Так? Хорошо. Обсуждение взаимодействий ru и en сообщества - это нормальная тема для чата? Если бы обсуждение не длилось слишком долго.

Comment: @PashaPash вам вроде предлагали это на мете написать. Правда, вы тогда написали, что, вероятно, получили бы бан за это :D

Comment: @Suvitruf это вполне нормальная тема для чата, IMHO, если она не заменяет стандартные инструменты модерации. По поводу обуждения бана - вот именно из-за таких случаев баны и не обсуждаются публично. Банят часто, и правила бана должны быть едины для всех. Известность участника не должна быть оправданием для нарушения правил. А публичное обсуждение некоторых банов - это лазейка для тех, кто известен в сообществе.

Comment: @Suvitruf Мы получили ситуацию, когда флейм не прекращается до тех пор, пока модератор лично не убедит **каждого** участника, который просто проходил мимо, что забаненный нарушил правила - ненормальна. Достаточно одного опоздавшего к общему обсуждению - и все начинается заново. Причем даже в случае явных и грубых нарушений правил - всегда можно сказать "а я не считаю что надо было банить" - и занять модератора еще на пару часов

Comment: @PashaPash лично я в чате спрашивал не про сам бан Атари, а про то, что вы думаете про его заявления и про недавнее обсуждение en сообщений.

Comment: @PashaPash про эту часть (что обсуждения растягиваются на дни) согласен. Может тогда на такие обсуждения создавать временные комнаты?

Comment: @Suvitruf да, это решение уже предложил Nofate. Скорее всего на нем и остановимся.

Comment: Подправьте вопрос, пожалуйста (оставьте один вопрос) - и его переоткроют :)

Comment: @Suvitruf  Если вас интересуют остальные вопросы, пожалуйста, задайте их отдельно.

Comment: @PashaPash отредактировал. Так пойдёт?

Comment: @Suvitruf [давайте как-то локализуем до одной проблемы. Надо оставить или первый вопрос (и тогда перевод FAQ, в развернутом виде) будет хорошим ответом. Или второй вопрос (про обсуждение администрации). Я бы предложил оставить первый.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46799015#46799015) Кроме того, пожалуйста, уберите раздел предыстория, который содержит ваш субъективный взгляд и не относится к самому вопросу. Он ве обсуждаемой темы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky там всего один вопрос про то, какие темы разрешены, про обсуждение администрации ни слова нету. Разве что, можно убрать часть про то, может ли сообщество менять список тем и задать это отдельным вопросом. Предыстория - это не субъективный взгляд, а просто пересказ. Я могу ссылки из чата приложить, если вы про это.

Comment: @Suvitruf Эта часть вопроса не имеет смысловой нагрузки в вопросе выше. Чтобы это понять, пожалуйста, ответьте себе на вопрос, например: «Станет ли вопрос хуже или непонятнее без этой части?»

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky просто это часть с конкретным примером. Думаете, стоит убирать? По-другому спрошу, делает ли эта часть вопрос хуже? Если нет, то, думаю, можно и оставить.

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, я думаю стоит убрать, так как вопрос и без нее понятен. С ней он становится размазанным.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky убрал.

Comment: @Suvitruf Большое спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky возможно стоит после ответа поставить метку [tag:faq] или [tag:важно].

Answer (score 7):

Поскольку [сообщества у нас саморегулируемые](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7692/10105), предлагаю взять власть в свои руки и самим, не дожидаясь разрешения начальства, установить список тем, разрешённых в *нашем* чате.

Я предлагаю разрешить следующие темы:

- Обсуждение вопросов нашего сайта, а также вопросов смежных подсайтов
- Обсуждение мета-вопросов, не укладывающееся в формат Меты
- Обсуждение политики модерации, вопросы к модераторам и администрации, не укладывающиеся в формат Меты
- Обсуждение переводов и локализации, если оно ещё кому-то интересно
- Приветствия/прощания и обсуждение жизни вне сайта
- Работа и связанные с ней вопросы

Я предлагаю запретить следующие темы:

- Политические обсуждения. Для них есть отдельный подчат.
- Обсуждения по конкретным языкам, для которых есть отдельный подчат.

Я также предлагаю не использовать этот список в качестве «белого списка»: чат должен оставаться неформальным. Если окажется, что какая-либо тема не нравится участникам чата, допустимость её должна устанавливаться на Мете **общим голосованием**, после чего список правил должен быть дополнен. До окончания общего голосования обсуждаемая тема должна считаться разрешённой по умолчанию.

Каждый, кто хочет запретить ту или иную тему, должен открыть обсуждение на Мете, и убедить сообщество в том, что это ограничение действительно необходимо. Единоличные решения в обход сообщества недопустимы.

В частности, «растягивание тем надолго» никакой проблемы для большей части сообщества не представляет, и возникает обычно вследствие важности данной темы. Следовательно, оно не может служить основанием для запрета. Недовольство какой-либо темой со стороны нескольких участников, хотя бы даже и модераторов, не может служить основанием для запрета этой темы в чате: единственным путём запрета должно быть голосование.

Я предлагаю всяческий перенос сообщений разрешить лишь в случае использования запрещённых тем. Я предлагаю удаление сообщений разрешить лишь в случае явного нарушения правил.

Модераторам, удаляющим или переносящим сообщения, рекомендуется указывать точную причину, не сводящуюся к «мне надоело». За использование «мне надоело» в качестве причины удаления сообщений должно быть стыдно. Те, кто удаляет критику себя, достоин презрения. И разумеется, причиной удаления сообщений не может быть личная неприязнь.

Comment: Предлагать можно много чего. Но если администрация это не поддержит, то толку ноль =/

Comment: @Suvitruf: А от администрации ничего не зависит, у нас самоуправление

Comment: Банят в чате модераторы/админы :D

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ну вот мы примем правила, и запретим им

Answer (score 2):

Нам не нужны явные списки тем, разрешенных для обсуждения в чате.

[Из FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#about):

> This site is an extension of The Stack Exchange Network, so discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at The Stack Exchange Network — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.

Круг тем и так ограничен правилами чата Stack Exchange, нет причин ограничивать его еще жестче именно для нашего сайта - ведь более жесткие ограничения подразумевают меньше *веселья* и больше усилий по модерированию.

Допустимы любые темы, допустимые к обсуждению на самом сайте, с поправкой на неформальность и локальный оффтопик. При этом допустимы к обсуждению вопросы модерирования - ведь мета у нас является неотъемлемой частью сайта, а не каким-то внешним ресурсом.

---

> Любые вопросы про сообщество и проблемы допустимы в чате, если они явно не нарушают CoC и не растягиваются на дни, тем самым забивая основную комнату.

Эта часть - больше ответ, чем вопрос, и я полностью с ней согласен :)

Comment: Вы забили дописать, что мета-вопросы тоже разрешены. Или "основная сайт" подразумевает мету?

Comment: Ещё интересно, когда остальная часть ответа добавится про доп. комнату и всё то, что обсуждалось.

Comment: "revolve around the same topics you'd find at The Stack Exchange Network" — т.е. можно обсуждать также онтопик из других сайтов сети? cc: @Suvitruf

Comment: @АндрейNOP меня этот вопрос в первую очередь и интересует. И никто пока ещё на дал ответа конкретного, всё вокруг да около.

Comment: @Suvitruf про мету вроде бы явно написал - вопросы модерирования допустимы. Насчет допкомнаты и сноса в нее флуда - это не совсем вопрос онтопика. Онтопик может скатиться в дикий многомесячный флуд, оставаясь при этом онтопиком. Из главной комнаты модсостав пока решил сносить во флудилку, вне зависимости от онтопичности.

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет, комнаты у нас все еще привязаны к сайту. Об этом явно [в диалоге создания комнаты сказано](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new): Rooms are each associated with a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network, and are expected to be on the same topic as that site - for example a room for the cooking site should be about cooking, as described in the cooking faq.

Comment: @Suvitruf ^^^^^

Comment: Никогда не создавал комнаты через этот диалог. При создании комнаты по кнопке "start a new room with this user" никакого диалога нет, комната создается сразу

Comment: @PashaPash вчера Кролик всего пару десятков сообщений написал, вы их перенесли во Флуд и забанили его. Не совсем понимаю тогда, за что.

Comment: @Suvitruf сообщения были просто перенесены, без какого-либо "наказания за оффтопик". После этого участник запостил сообщение, которое я посчитал оскорбительным - и я поставил на него флаг. К   онтопичности это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @Suvitruf т.е. онтопик онтопиком, но CoC и "Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members" у нас все еще действует.

Comment: @PashaPash ну, я сообщения не видел того, не знаю, что там было. Но перенесли вы сообщения до, по вашему мнению, нарушения CoC. Неувязочка. Я просто не понимаю, какие критерии переноса. Количество сообщений?

Comment: @Suvitruf да, количество сообщений + история обсуждения той же темы в том же чате теми же участниками + новизна аргументов.

Comment: Вы передёргиваете. По факту единственный модератор очень существенно ограничивает тематику, особенно обсуждение своих ошибок.

Comment: @VladD у нас есть отличная инструкция по оспариванию действий модератора в чате - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7693/177221, предлагаю вам ей воспользоваться.

Comment: @PashaPash: Я бы очень хотел, чтобы вы хоть раз в жизни ей воспользовались, а потом говорили, не зная что.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну и я не вижу смысла обсуждать ваше поведение с Николасом, а других модераторов у нас нет, как бы вы не пытались представить ситуацию по-другому.

Comment: @VladD в таком случае вам остаётся только обратиться через форму на MSE. Правда, ответ будет только через несколько месяцев, если вовсе будет)

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я пойду другим путём. ;)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, по отношению к обсуждаемым вопросам в беседке проще идти от запретительных списков и правила: всё что не запрещено, то <s>запретим чуть позднее</s> разрешено.