# Можно ли отправить в отставку всех модераторов?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Считаю,что на сайте невозможно уже дышать. Одни модераторы гоняют людей просто потому, что у них нет настроения. Другие же просто ничего не делают, их работы не видно.

Вы все себя изжили! Сайт требует новых лиц.

---

Простейший пример модераторского беспредела. Нельзя просто выразить своё мнение. Мнение ДОЛЖНО нравиться г-ину модератору.
Какой пункт правил я нарушил? Не соблаговолите ли Вы, дать пруф.

[image: альт]

Да и вообще, сайт вроде как создан для помощи друг другу.
Возьмём меня. Три созданных вопроса.
Все они - заминусованы!
На один кое-как дан ответ, спустя Н-дней.

Люди делятся на три категории, тихоминусящие всё подряд, вторые - гоняющиеся за рейтингом, которые ради рейтинга готовы поставить лишний пробел или убрать лишнею запятую и 3-е, как мамонты, готовые чем-то помочь.

Если тут сообщество крутых "программистов", так и напишите, мол новичкам не рады.

Закройте регистрацию, поднимайте рейт друг другу, правьте друг друга и всё будет чудесно :)

Comment: Отправить, думаю, можно, а на их место есть желающие прийти разгребать завалы по тревогам и закрытиям вопросов? Так что зачем это вам?

Comment: Модераторский беспредел просто зашкаливает. Почему такого в англоязычной версии нет?

Comment: Вы уверены, что понимаете, кто такие модераторы на SO, и чем именно они занимаются? В чем проявляется беспредел? Лично вас "гоняют"? Кого-то еще из участников?

Comment: Как я понимаю, основная проблема в том, что на ваши вопросы не отвечают (или не отвечают достаточно быстро). Во-первых, нужно понимать, что здесь сидят не всезнающие боги, которые сходу могут дать ответ на любой вопрос, поэтому может пройти какое-то время, чтобы нашелся человек, который сможет вам помочь. Во-вторых, вам стоит почитать вот этот раздел справки: [*Что делать, если никто не отвечает на мой вопрос?*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: И, кстати, я так и не увидел причину, по которой вы дали ответ, скриншот которого приложен к вопросу. Вы указываете его как причину вашего требования отставки всех модераторов, но что послужило поводом дать тот ответ - не понятно.

Answer (score 9):

1. Если кто-то нарушил правила в отношении вас (сообщение, комментарий и т.п), то вы всегда можете оставить тревогу на его сообщении.
2. Если у вас конфликт с каким-то из модераторов, то [этот ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7693/15479) вам поможет.
3. Хорошо бы в вопросе описать конкретные проблемы, иначе мы помочь вам не сможем =/
4. Из того, что я вижу по аналитике, время обработки тревог менее часа.
5. > их работы не видно

   Так и должно быть. Если работы модератора не видно, значит они работают хорошо.
6. Отвечая же на ваш вопрос в целом - да, можно, если они нарушили правила.

---

**Обновлено:** касательно ваших вопрос. К примеру, [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1032101/15479). Достаточно почитать правила и поправить вопрос. Но вы почему-то проблему видите не в самом вопросе, а в тех, кто старался вам помочь.

Answer (score 6):

Подобные требования должны быть подкреплены словами (из правил, справки или каких-либо других соглашений, принятых здесь) и делами представителей "исполнительной власти", которые нарушают оные соглашения, дабы у вас был действенный повод начать шаги по лишению данных пользователей ромба справа от их "имени". В противном случае это необоснованные заявления, особенно такого рода.

> Нельзя просто выразить своё мнение. Мнение ДОЛЖНО нравиться г-ину
>   модератору.

Если вы понимаете, что ваше мнение обязательно не понравится пользователю с ромбом, то постарайтесь его преподнести так, чтобы у оного не появилось поводов по "устранению" такого сообщения. Не зря же советские фильмы, книги, песни и прочие по количеству повторных показов на порядок выше современных "творений". И одной из причин было **умение** их создателей **действовать в условиях ограничений**. Это развивает и учит творчески мыслить при решении поставленных — вами в том числе — задач.

> Какой пункт правил я нарушил?

Вот описание подобного случая в Справке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

> Будьте дружелюбными
>
> Отвечая на вопросы или щедро делясь своими знаниями, помните, что все
>   мы здесь, чтобы вместе учиться чему-то новому. Будьте
>   **доброжелательны** и терпеливы, особенно с теми, кто может знать меньше, чем вы. И не забудьте про чувство юмора, так, на всякий
>   случай.

Ваше пожелание было недоброжелательным, поэтому итог закономерен.